# binance python get api

Tags: python, api

Here is a description of long short ratio that I want to download

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#long-short-ratio

In that site, there is a sentence: GET /futures/data/globalLongShortAccountRatio

Please tell me the code in python (import requests) for example "BTCUSDT", "5M" CASE

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have done so far, but this may help you i think:

```
def get_global_long_short_accounts(self, symbol: 'str', period: 'str', startTime: 'str' = None, endTime: 'str' = None, limit: 'int' = 30) -> any:
    """
    Long/Short Ratio (MARKET_DATA)
    GET /futures/data/globalLongShortAccountRatio
    """
    response = call_sync(self.request_impl.get_global_long_short_accounts(symbol, period, startTime, endTime, limit))
    self.refresh_limits(response[1])
    return response[0]
```

can read up on it here:

```
https://github.com/Binance-docs/Binance_Futures_python/blob/master/binance_f/requestclient.py

https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md
```